# Conversion between numeric types of the same kind

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, primitive-types

I was reading http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/. It says that:

- > Otherwise, if the conversion is between numeric types of the same kind
  >   (integer-to-integer or floating-to-floating), the conversion is valid,
  >   but the value is implementation-specific (and may not be portable).

But I really didn't understand what does the above quote mean to say? Will someone please explain it using an simple example? Why conversion between numeric type of same kind results in implementation-specific value? What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider the following example:

```cpp
    long long int lli = 5000000000;
    long int li;
    int i;
    li = lli;
    i = li;
```

Can you predict the values of `lli`, `li` and `i`? Or whether `li` and `i` have the same value?

Answer is - values depend on the number of bytes allocated for each type!
I.e. for some cases `int` is equal to `long int`, for others `long int` is equal to `long long int`, but in general `long`er types just CAN be longer. Similar (in sense of memory size) for `float`, `double` and `long double`.

Comment: So, is it possible that long is not larger than int on Some of the C++ implementation? Do you know such implementation?

Comment: @PravasiMeet That's the common case actually. Visual Studio x86 and x64 and gcc x86 have sizeof(long) == sizeof(int) if I'm not mistaken and I wouldn't be surprised if clang did the same.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: yes gcc 5.2.0 & clang 3.5.0 did the same. See live demo http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IsGDktKO5VUBY0KV & http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6icDnbxu4hAIkwMN. I got 5000000000 as an output 3 times. But when I run it on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ it gives me 5000000000 705032704 705032704 as an output. I hope the original answer writer add these links into his answer.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet refers to narrowing conversions between integral and floating point types respectively. That is, it states that although a conversion between integral types or between floating point types is valid, the resulting value will be implementation defined.

As an example consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  long long lgm = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
  std::cout << std::hex << lgm << std::endl;
  int i = lgm;
  std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;

  long double ldb = std::numeric_limits<long double>::max();
  std::cout << std::hex << ldb << std::endl;
  double db = ldb;
  std::cout << std::hex << db << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
7fffffffffffffff
ffffffff
1.18973e+4932
inf
```

As you can see the maximum value of `long long` integer exceeds the capacity of a plain integer. However you can convert a `long long` to an `int` (i.e., the conversion is valid), but due to the fact that the `int` can't hold the maximum value of a `long long` there cannot be an accurate conversion. Thus, the value of the resulting `int` is left to be decided by the implementation. The same holds true for the conversion between `long double` and `double`.